# JBoss 5.1 datasource configuration using external properties

Tags: java, properties, datasource, jboss5.x

Instead of giving the url, driver, username and password I would like to read those properties from a properties file which I give to jboss on the startup script as a JVM argument.

```
/data/jboss/bin/run.sh -c myApp -Dds.conffile=/some/path/ds.properties
```

I want to use properties in ds.properties to configure my jndi datasource like this:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MyDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>${db.url}</connection-url>
    <driver-class>${db.driver}</driver-class>
    <user-name>${db.username}</user-name>
    <password>${db.password}</password>
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

How can I reference the properties in ds.properties inside my app-ds.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can write own driver (implement java.sql.Driver), set JDBC Driver Class and Connection URL for that driver.
Inside driver class initialize and register real driver with your settings.